# Computing the Taylor expansion of the square root of cos(z),

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, power-series, exponential-function, taylor-expansion

Let $\large f(z)=\sqrt{cosz}$ with the branch of the square root chosen so that $f(0)=1$.

Consider the power series expansion of $f(z)$ in powers of $z$.

Part 1) Compute the first three non-zero terms of the power series explicitly.

Part 2) What is the radius of convergence of this series?

My work:

I think that I am possibly not doing the expansion correctly.

First off, write

$$f(z) = \sqrt{cosz} = \large e^{\large \frac{1}{2}log(cos(z))}$$

To fulfill $f(0) = 1$, I think the principal branch, having $-\pi \ Arg(z) \le \pi$ works just fine.

Then my series expansion is (using the above equation, and using the exponential function)

$$f(z) = \sqrt{cosz} = e^{\large \frac{1}{2}log(cos(z))}$$

$$= \large \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\large \frac{1}{2}log(cos(z))^n}{n!}$$

$$= 1+ \frac {1}{2}log(cos(z)) + \frac {1}{8}log^2(cos(z)) + ... $$

Have I computed the first three terms correctly?  Or, have I not said much at all with this expansion, and that I have possibly missed the point?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have expanded in $\log\cos z,$ whereas the assignment is probably to expand in $z.$

If you know the series expansion of $\cos,$ then the series of its square root can be computed term by term from

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\right)^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^na_ia_{n-i}\right)z^n$$

where the sum between brackets on the left hand side is the required expansion.

In degree zero this gives $a_0=1$ (we discard $a_0=-1$ because it represents the other branch of the square root). The next equation is $a_0a_1+a_1a_0=0,$ from which you deduce $a_1=0,$ and so on.

The radius of convergence is determined by the maximum disk around the origin that does not contain any singularities. The closest singularities to the origin occur at $z=\pm\frac\pi2.$

Comment: Hi @Justpassingby, can you please elaborate a little bit on the first equation?  Is the L.H.S. the square of the Taylor series of $\sqrt{cos(z)}$?  What is the R.H.S.?  Thanks,

Comment: That's the idea. The right hand side is the expansion of $\cos z$ expressed with the unknown coefficients from the expansion of $\sqrt{\cos z}.$ Since we already know the expansion of $\cos z$ we can use the equation to find the unknown coefficients.

Comment: Hi @Justpassingby, hmm...setting up the equations, I get the first equation is $(a_0)^2 = 1$ ... then wouldn't the $a_0$ be $+/- 1$?

Comment: Yes but that represents the other branch of the square root. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Ok, got it @Justpassingby, I think I got it all now.  Thanks so much for your help -- have a great night :-)

Comment: fun problem, btw, it's a nice break from computing more tedious numbers like residues :-)